# Right place for Juniper related questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Sometimes when I'm not sure where a question belongs, I'll google `stackexchange <tag>`.  I did this with Junos/Juniper.  The entire first page of results are from `networkengineering.stackexchange.com` so I [posted there](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57072/destination-nat-based-on-subdomain).

It was closed as off-topic and someone commented that SF was the proper place to post.

Here is the tag usage breakdown:

```
SF: 
 Juniper:       257
 Junos:         58

NE:
 Juniper:       316
 Juniper-Junos: 215
 Juniper-srx:   80
 Juinper-ex:    62
 Juniper-mx:    39
```

So what is the consensus? Does it depend on the question as the commenter implied?

Comment: Did you mean to ask _only us_ this question? I do not see that you also asked the Network Engineering crowd on their meta.

Comment: I guess I was more making sure it was okay to post here. They'd already told me it wasn't okay to post there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment about the topicality at Network Engineering except to state what its moderator already told you:

> OK. Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You should ask questions about things like DNS and web stuff on Server Fault. – Ron Maupin♦ [Feb 19 at 15:51](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57072/destination-nat-based-on-subdomain#comment99159_57072)

You're trying to do something at Layer 7, which they simply don't deal with at all.

As for us, questions about Juniper hardware and JunOS are welcome at SF regardless of what OSI layer you are working at.

Comment: I didn't even notice that was a mod until I read your answer.  Thanks for the response, I'd say my question is fully answered, whether it makes sense to me or not :)